# Java Compiler executes return before if statement

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, jit

**Is there any possibility that `java compiler` ignores `if statement` in java while optimizing?**

We have two environments [A and B identical] and the same code is deployed on both the environments.
The code has one method which has code like below :

```
private LocaleCodeValue getDefaultLocaleCodeValue(String code) {
String value = code;
if (code.contains("_")) value = code.substring(0, code.lastIndexOf("_"));
return new LocaleCodeValue(code, value);
}
```

This should work both the environments.

**However, on environment B is sometimes ignore the if statement and directly return the object while the condition is true. For debugging we performed the actions that will lead to condition to true. It works for anv A but not B (sometimes). But we are 100 % sure that the condition was true always.** after many days of debugging we come a conclusion that it might be possible that JIT compiler is optimizing the code and may ignoring the if statement.

So we changed the code to like below :

```
private LocaleCodeValue getDefaultLocaleCodeValue(String code) {
    String value = code;
    if (code.contains("_")) {
     value = code.substring(0, code.lastIndexOf("_"));
     return new LocaleCodeValue(code, value);
    }
    return new LocaleCodeValue(code, value);
    }
```

and now the code works as expected.

I agree that this issue is very hard to reproduce, However I am curious is someone has faced problem like this? or is there any possibility that java compiler is messing with this?

```
Java Image : image: openjdk:10-jdk-slim
```

Comment: An exception may be thrown

Comment: Either your assumption is wrong and on env B the condition is *not* true when you think it is, or you found a bug in the compiler. The two implementations should be 100% equivalent. Given that finding this huge of a bug in a widely deployed application seems farfetched I guess that the problem is simply that the condition is false when you expected it to be true. If you want more help please provide an example code that we can actually run and test..

Comment: We can't guess based on what you've shown.  SHOW THE ACTUAL CODE, including its context (in a try-block?). The condition could be throwing an exception and if the return is in a finally block or the exception is ignored this could occur.

Comment: Well there _might_ be situations where this could happen (at least because the JIT is a piece of software that can contain bugs after all) but I'd first look for an error in my part of the equation. Can you elaborate on what you're actually doing (preferably a [mre]) and on the exact Jave version you're using?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I do agree with you, however we are 100% sure that the condition was always true. We debugged this for almost 5 days. Please believe.

Comment: What’s the condition? What’s within the if? What’s the context? How do you execute it?

Comment: Code analysis? Integer== goes wrong for n>128. Persistence problems. Wrong load balancing, routing. Add some logging.

Comment: I do *believe* that Java has run for far more than 5 days. You debugging for 5 days does not really force the conclusion that the compiler is wrong. And given that you show basically nothing of your code there is no reason to doubt the compiler is correct / does not contain a bug.

Comment: @luk2302 I agree with you all, that's why I added that it's very hard to reproduce. I could not say anything except that. But This is was we have analyzed.

Comment: Belief and certainty is not the same as objective fact.  (There are people who are 100% sure that the earth is flat!)  We need to see the real code here .... if you want an informed answer.

Comment: @StephenC Let me add the minimal code for this. So that we can proceed further.

Comment: most likely your guys overlook something.If java got wrong on this, it won't even be an existing programming language.

Comment: Did you (in production) log the result of that condition (before using it in the if), then whether you entered the if-block?

Comment: @StephenC I have updated the code.

Comment: Floating point without strictfp could cause minor differences.

Comment: @MehrajMalik have you logged what `code.contains("_")` had returned? It could be a symbol visually similar to `_`

Comment: Are you sure that the JVM's on both servers are using the same character encoding for strings and not, say, UTF-8 on one and windows-1252 on the other? (you can check using `Charset.defaultCharset().displayName()`) conversion earlier in the code could lead to unexpected results if they are.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any possibility that java compiler is messing with this?

In theory yes.  It is mathematically possible.

In practice ... it is more likely that you are either missing something, or you have a misconception about some aspect of Java's behavior.  (For example, what makes a program thread-safe.)

Java is used by millions of programmers.  Bugs do get found, but the chances that any given unexpected / not understood behavior in some "ordinary looking" code is due to a compiler bug are miniscule.

(And besides, unless you can provide evidence of the supposed compiler bug in the form of a reproducible testcase:

1. you won't be able to report it / get a fix for it, and
2. you won't have any *logical* basis for believing that your workaround is actually curing the problem.  (It could simply be reducing its probability, or moving it somewhere else.)

---

> The code has one method which has code like below :

(Is it that the real code?  Or is it just "like" it?  And if it is just "like" it, how does it differ from the real code?)

```
private LocaleCodeValue getDefaultLocaleCodeValue(String code) {
    String value = code;
    if (code.contains("_")) 
        value = code.substring(0, code.lastIndexOf("_"));
    return new LocaleCodeValue(code, value);
}
```

Possibility #0.  The problem is that either the input to or the output of this method is not what you think it is.  (Noting that if an application is multi-threaded, the use of a debugger or the addition of tracing or logging can alter the application's behavior.  In ways that may hide the actual evidence.)

Possibility #1.  The problem is in the `LocaleCodeValue` constructor.

Possibility #2.  Homoglyphs: under some circumstances you are getting some character that *looks* like the `'_'` character, but actually isn't.

Possibility #3.  Somewhere else in the codebase is some code that is using nasty reflection to mutate `String` values, and it just happens to mutate the value of `code`.  It may not even be doing that during the call to this method ... if it happens on a different thread.

Possibility #4.  Somewhere in the codebase some buggy native code is being called, and that is trampling something.

Possibility #5.  A hardware error.

Possibility #6.  The code that you are running doesn't match the source code that you are looking at; e.g. you have a problem with your build or deployment processes.

and

Possibility #7.  There is some subtle but important difference between what you have shown us and the real code.

My bet would be on #0, #6 or #7 (except that you just said not #7).

---

If, despite all of the other possibilities, you still think you have a compiler bug, the next steps would be to examine bytecodes for errors, and then get the JVM to dump the JIT-compiled native code and examine that.  In addition, you need to create a reproducible example that (for example) Oracle's Java engineers can work on.

Comment: This is the exact code. Yes, this is all about `might have happened` as there is no string point saying that this is a bug in compiler. This was experienced and hence asked a question if someone has faced the problem like this. BTW thanks for your help :)